# ¿Cómo devolver todos los resultados de una consulta hecha dentro de un for each en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Saludos excelente día tengan todos, tengo una situación con la siguiente problemática, el usuario selecciona una lista de valores, y esa misma la recibo, la convierto ne un array y despues la separo para poder realizar un for each y ejecutar una instrucción, sin embargo al ejecutarse, no me retorna todos los valores, solo me retorna el ultimo de la lista[Array].

De esta forma lo recibo:
`public IEnumerable<LstDetalle> GetDetalleSolicitudes(string Solicitudes)`

Y así lo convierto:

```
                    
                    
                    string[] ArrayLst = Solicitudes.Split(',');

                    foreach (string item in ArrayLst)
                    {
                       consulta = db.Database.SqlQuery<LstDetalle>(@"SELECT [map1],[map2] FROM 
                        a.Solicitud = @sol",
                        new SqlParameter("@sol", Convert.ToInt32(item) )).ToList();
                    }

                    return consulta;
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que me retorne todos los valores en la lista que se indican?
Y no solo un solo valor.

Por su atención y ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

aqui de nuevo por si a alguien le llegara a servir encontre la solucion realizando lo siguiente:

```
 List<LstDetalle> consulta1 = new List<LstDetalle>();
                //Separa los elementos
                string[] ArrayLst = Solicitudes.Split(',');
                //creo una lista para la consulta
                List<LstDetalle> consulta = new List<LstDetalle>();
                //por cada valor que tenga el array
                foreach (string item in ArrayLst)
                { //ejecuto la conuslta
                   consulta1 = db.Database.SqlQuery<LstDetalle>(@"SELECT [Mapeos] FROM [TuTabla] where a.Solicitud = @sol ",
                    new SqlParameter("@sol", Convert.ToInt32(item) )).ToList();
                      //Va reccoriendo el elemento asi que hago de nuevo un for each
                    foreach (var i in consulta1)
                    {  //creo una nueva lista para mapear lo que necesito y añadirlo a la lista nueva
                        LstDetalle com = new LstDetalle();
                        com.Telefono_Activacion = i.Telefono_Activacion;
                        consulta.Add(com); //lo agrego
                    }

                }
                //asi al retorna habra recorrido y agregado a la lista los elementos y retornara todos los valores y no solo el ultimo
                return consulta;
```