# foreach solo muestra el ultimo dato C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, foreach

Cargo 2 listas para buscar ciertos atributos y guardarlos en una nueva lista, y aunque lo hace bien hasta cierto punto solo guarda el ultimo objeto que recorre el foreach.

```
         foreach (var i in remeresu)
        {
            foreach (var t in trabajadores)
            {

                if (t.nrt_ruttr == i.nrt_ruttr && i.cod_conce == 910)
                {
                    listpapeleta.rutTra = t.nrt_ruttr;
                    listpapeleta.nombre = t.nom_nomtr + " " + t.nom_appat;
                    listpapeleta.fechaPago = (DateTime)i.fec_pago;
                    listarPapeleta.Add(listpapeleta);
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

y esta la retorno a una vista
`return View(listarPapeleta);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas modificando la misma referencia del objeto `listpapeleta` en cada iteración del bucle. Esto provoca que todos los elementos que se almacenen en la lista contengan exactamente la misma información de la última modificación que sufrió el objeto. Para arreglarlo tienes que crear un nuevo objeto antes de modificar los atributos de este:

```
foreach (var i in remeresu)
{
    foreach (var t in trabajadores)
    {
        if (t.nrt_ruttr == i.nrt_ruttr && i.cod_conce == 910)
        {
            /* Reservar espacio en memoria */
            listpapeleta = new ListPapeleta(); // O el nombre que le tengas dado a esa clase

            /* Modificar el nuevo objeto */
            listpapeleta.rutTra = t.nrt_ruttr;
            listpapeleta.nombre = t.nom_nomtr + " " + t.nom_appat;
            listpapeleta.fechaPago = (DateTime)i.fec_pago;

            /* Añadir a la lista */
            listarPapeleta.Add(listpapeleta);
         } 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Marco este comentario como respuesta por que da la explicación del problema, además de la solución mucha gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si te sea de mucha ayuda lo siguiente, lo que yo hice no se si sea la manera correcta u optima pero a mi me ayudo, lo que realice fue crear dos nuevas listas en el código, una en donde hago referencia a la consulta, y otra en donde voy agregando los resultados por cada iteración.

```
      List<ListPapeleta> datos= new List<ListPapeleta>();       
     foreach (var t in trabajores)
          {     
            if (t.nrt_ruttr == i.nrt_ruttr && i.cod_conce == 910)
               {
                     listpapeleta lst = new ListPapeleta();

                      lst.rutTra = t.nrt_ruttr; 

                      datos.Add(com); //lo agrego
                 }
                    
             }
                //asi al retorna habra recorrido y agregado a la lista los elementos y retornara todos los valores y no solo el ultimo
                return datos;
```

Tenia una misma situación de otra forma: pero igual te dejo la pregunta

[¿Cómo devolver todos los resultados de una consulta hecha dentro de un for each en C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422481/c%c3%b3mo-devolver-todos-los-resultados-de-una-consulta-hecha-dentro-de-un-for-each)

Comment: Gracias por tu propuesta efectivamente era en lo que estaba fallando!